# Postfix with Pgsql support

Tags: centos, postfix, postgresql

I'm trying to find an alternative repo with postfix that has pgsql support on Cenots 6.

I previously used CentAlt but since that seems to be dead now i'm trying to find an alternative.

I would prefer not to compile postfix from source if at all possible.

I've looked online and at other posts on here but can't find an answer that works.

Does anyone know of any repos that comes with postfix/w pgsql support or a repo that includes postfix-pgsql?

Answer (score 5):

Centos7 does not include PgSQl support in postfix in base repository, you'll have to use centosplus repository

```
postconf -c /etc/postfix -m | grep sql
mysql
```

As root

```
yum install yum-priorities
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
  Add the following to sections base and update
    exclude=postfix-*
    priority=1 
  Modify the following in section centosplus
    priority=2
    enabled=1
  Save and exit

yum erase postfix
yum install postfix
postconf -c /etc/postfix -m | grep sql
  mysql
  pgsql
```

Answer (score 2):

CentOS appears to include PGSQL support these days, in version 6 at least:

```
mail ~ # postconf -c /etc/postfix -m | grep sql
mysql
pgsql
mail ~ # rpm -qa | grep postfix
postfix-2.11.0-0.el6.x86_64
mail ~ # cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```